# Manage 10-15 columns on a single screen (Android App)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tablelayout

Just wondering if we can do something like [this](http://zurb.com/article/982/a-new-take-on-responsive-tables) using android code (native app) or even a better method to handle multiple columns on a single screen. I have searched a lot but all I find is done through CSS & JS rather than android code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<LinearLayout orientation="horizontal">
    <LinearLayout orientation="vertical>
        <!-- first column fixed -->
    </LinearLayout>
    <HorizontalScrollView>
        <LinearLayout orientation="horizontal">
            <LinearLayout orientation="vertical>
                <!-- second column -->
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout orientation="vertical>
                <!-- third column -->
            </LinearLayout>
            <!-- etc -->
        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

You get the gist.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try to do this with HorizontalScrollView and items in it that are single columns (each column could be a single LinearLayout with other views in it)?

Comment: I tried doing that but there are 2 issues. Firstly left header also moves. Secondly each individual row scrolls rather than the table as a whole

Comment: I mean one HorizontalScrollView with many elements, not a single scroll view for every column